# How to attach a file to a form in Unity?

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, multipartform-data

I am currently trying to make a post request with a file attached to the form but I found out that it is not the file I have attached but just the path to the file.

My question is how do I get this file and attach it to the form?

Here is my code so far:

```
    string altPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "nice-work.wav");

 
    List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
    formData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("wavfile", altPath));

    UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, formData);
    yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

    if (uwr.isNetworkError)
    {
        Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
    }
```

the variable altPath is the path but not the file and this leads to failed post request.

Comment: you need to convert that file in byte array and then upload it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [`MultipartFormFileSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html) the constructor you are currently using is

```
MultipartFormFileSection(string data, string fileName)
```

which is of course not what you want to do.

You rather have to actually read the according file content e.g. simply using [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes)

```
...

var multiPartSectionName = "wavfile";
var fileName = "nice-work.wav";
var altPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, fileName);
var data = File.ReadAllBytes(altPath);

var formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>
{
    new MultipartFormFileSection(multiPartSectionName, data, fileName)
};

...
```

or depending on your server side needs

```
...

var formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>
{
    new MultipartFormFileSection(fileName, data)
};

...
```

---

Though have in mind that `ReadAllBytes` is a synchronous (blocking) call and for larger files you might rather want to use some asynchronous approach.